# Beyond Hilton-Milner Theorem for an Intersecting Family? 

Tags: co.combinatorics

Hilton-Milner tells us about an intersecting family of $k$-size subsets $\mathcal{F}$ from $\binom{[n]}{k}$:
If $|\mathcal{F}| > \binom{n-1}{k-1}-\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}+1$, then all elements of $\mathcal{F}$ share at least 1 element of [n].

The theorem classifies the non-trivial $\mathcal{F}$ if equality occurs i.e. $|\mathcal{F}| = \binom{n-1}{k-1}-\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}+1$.

I was wondering if there are known results/literature to see on classifications with $|\mathcal{F}| < \binom{n-1}{k-1}-\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}+1$, particularly values very close to equality?

I am currently looking at the case of $n=7$, and $k=3$ to get an idea of this (i.e. what can be said about an intersecting family of size 12 < $\binom{6}{2}-\binom{3}{2}+1?)$.

Comment: Does the question refer somehow to the Hilton-Milnor theorem (named after Peter Hilton and John Milnor) on homotopy groups of wedges of spheres?

Comment: No, this is a set theory result with Anthony Hilton and Eric Milner.

Comment: The set-theory tag seems misplaced here, since the topic is really finite combinatorics. 

Answer (score 5):

There are at least three types of results that spring to mind. One is the Ahlswede-Khachatrian theorem ("the complete intersection theorem"), which for each $n$ and $k < n/2$ will give you tight upper bounds for $t$-intersecting families (families in which every two sets intersect in at least $t$ points). For example, if $k \leq n/3 + 1$ then a $2$-intersecting family has size at most $\binom{n-2}{k-2}$, and so if $|\mathcal{F}| > \binom{n-2}{k-2}$ then there are two sets $S,T \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $|S \cap T| = 1$. They also have a matching Hilton-Milner type result, in which the family is required to have empty intersection ("the complete non-trivial intersection theorem").

A second one is stability results. Such results show that if $|\mathcal{F}| = (1-\epsilon)\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ then there is an element belonging to a $1-O(\epsilon)$ fraction of the sets. One such result is due to Friedgut ("on the measure of intersecting families, uniqueness and stability"), another is due to Keevash ("shadows and intersections: stability and new proofs").

A third one is due to Dinur and Friedgut ("intersecting families are essentially contained in juntas"). For $k = cn$, they show that *any* intersecting family essentially depends on $O(1)$ points, where the constant depends on $c$. For $k = o(n)$, they can show that *any* intersecting family has an element common to all but $C \binom{n-2}{k-2}$ of the sets.

Comment: Dinur and Friedgut: http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0963548308009309